# On which machine we should install WAL-G?

Tags: postgresql, high-availability, patroni

We are using PostgreSQL version 12.1. Currently we have high availability and automatic failover using Patroni and it's working fine.

Now we are planning for disaster recovery and we are planning to use WAL-G for this.

We read some article to know that on which machine we should install WAL-G master, slave or both? But couldn't get a clear idea.

Can you please help us to know on which machine should we set up WAL-G?

Answer (score 0):

As [WAL-G](https://github.com/wal-g/wal-g#installation) helps you both pushing and pulling backups and WAL to and from a storage, you have to install it on both the master and replica.

You can consider using a ready-made image, like [Spilo](https://github.com/zalando/spilo), which would solve these issues for you.

Finally, there is official [Patroni support on GitHub](https://github.com/zalando/patroni/issues), you will get answers way faster there.